# I'm getting an 'NSCalendar?' does not have a member named 'components' error since XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) update

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, nspredicate

This update has broken several things for me.

**Here is the code:**

```
func convertStartAndExpiryDateFromPickerIntoString(datePicker: UIDatePicker) -> String {
    let dateFromPicker = datePicker.date
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    let unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit
    let components = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: dateFromPicker)
    return "\(months.objectAtIndex(components.month)) \(components.day)"

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Define "no longer working".

Comment: @HotLicks my bad. Didn't realise I didn't provide enough info. I've edited my post title accordingly.

Comment: I can't reconcile this question's title with the code, but the error in your title suggests that you're trying to access `components` on a `NSCalendar?` optional. You have to unwrap that optional (e.g. with `!` forced unwrapping operator) before you can use the object it references.

Comment: This was the issue. Not sure why it has been working all this time for me though. I had the wrong code pasted by the way.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 added failable initializers, so `NSCalendar(...)` now returns an optional `NSCalendar?` that must be unwrapped.  Before, in Xcode 6.0 it returned a regular `NSCalendar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwrapping as Rob suggested worked.

```
func convertStartAndExpiryDateFromPickerIntoString(datePicker: UIDatePicker) -> String {
        let dateFromPicker = datePicker.date
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
        let unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit
        let components = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: dateFromPicker)
        return "\(months.objectAtIndex(components.month)) \(components.day)"

    }
```